# Apache2 - Туннелирование WS-протокола

Tags: apache, сервер, websocket, прокси

Создал виртуальный домен: `socketserver.site.com`, в нем разместил:

```
ProxyPass / ws://ip:3333
ProxyPassReverse / ws://ip:3333
```

Включил `mod_proxy` и `mod_proxy_wstunnel`.

Все хорошо работает, соединение устанавливается. Но хотелось бы, чтобы при открытии сайта `socketserver.site.com`, не выдавал ошибку `500`(ясное дело, почему он это делает)

нельзя ли как-то сделать, что бы при обращении браузера, он не пытался подключиться к серверу `ws`, а чтобы срабатывал обычный `HTTP-запрос`, с загрузкой `index.html`